# If $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$, and $G$ is finite, prove that $[K\colon (H\cap K)]\leq [G\colon H]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

Let $H,K$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$. Prove that $[K\colon (H\cap K)]\leq [G\colon H]$.

This is what I have:

$[K\colon (H\cap K)] = |\left\{ a(H\cap K) \mid  a\in K\right\}|$

$[G\colon H] = |\left\{ bH \mid b\in G\right\}|$

Going this direction, I was thinking I could define an injective function to map the cosets of $(H\cap K)$ to the cosets of $H$. I'm having trouble thinking through it though.

I also recognize that:

$[K\colon (H\cap K)]$ = $|K|\over|(H\cap K)|$

$[G\colon H]$ = $|G|\over|H|$

and also that the order of $(H\cap K)$ divides both $|H|$ and $|K|$.

I'm not sure how to tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{S}=\{x(H \cap K): x \in K\}$, the set of left cosets of the subgroup $H \cap K$ in $K$. Let $\mathcal{T}=\{gH : g \in G\}$, the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$. We are going to define a map $f : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathcal{T}$, by $f(x(H \cap K))= xH$. We have to show two things: the map is well defined (does not depend on a particular coset representative) and the map is injective.

For the first: assume $x(H \cap K)=y(H \cap K)$, with $x, y \in K$. Then $x^{-1}y \in H \cap K$, so in particular $x^{-1}y \in H$. This gives $xH=yH$ and $f$ is well defined.

Suppose $f(x(H \cap K))=f(y(H \cap K))$ for some $x,y \in K$. Then $xH=yH$. This is equivalent to $x^{-1}y \in H$. But since $K$ is a subgroup, also $x^{-1}y \in K$. So $x^{-1}y \in H \cap K$ and this yields $x(H \cap K)=y(H \cap K)$. So $f$ is injective.